# why a constructor doesn't affect the properties in this example

Tags: c#

I am wondering why when we have   `p = new Person("TOM", 999);` by calling     `fred.PrintInfo();`
It doesn't change the p to TOM and 999 but by using  p.age = 99; we can change the fred's age well the both constructor and properties are public then what is here that I am missing? I don't want to do anything with this code I just want the reason.

```
using System;

class Person
{
    public string fullName;
    public int age;

    public Person(string n, int a)
    {
        fullName = n;
        age = a;
    }

    public void PrintInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1} years old", fullName, age);
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void SendAPersonByValue(Person p)
    {
        p.age = 99;

        p = new Person("TOM", 999);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Person fred = new Person("Fred", 12);
        fred.PrintInfo();
        SendAPersonByValue(fred);
        fred.PrintInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Read this... : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`fred` points to some particular location in memory:

```
           +------------+
fred ----> | Fred    12 |
           +------------+
```

Upon calling SendAPersonByValue, `p` points to that same location:

```
           +------------+
fred ----> | Fred    12 |
           +------------+
              ^
  p  ---------+
```

`p.age = 99;` now changes the value in memory:

```
           +------------+
fred ----> | Fred    99 |
           +------------+
              ^
  p  ---------+
```

whereas `new Person("TOM", 999);` creates a *new* Person in memory, and `p = ...` makes `p` point to it:

```
           +------------+
fred ----> | Fred    99 |
           +------------+

           +------------+
  p  ----> | TOM    999 |
           +------------+
```

And this is exactly why `fred` still contains `Fred, 99`.

---

Now, if you were to pass `fred` as a [`ref` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx), `p` would become an *alias* for `fred`:

```
             +------------+
fred/p ----> | Fred    12 |
             +------------+
```

After `p.age = 99`:

```
             +------------+
fred/p ----> | Fred    99 |
             +------------+
```

After `p = new Person("TOM", 999);`:

```
             +------------+
             | Fred    99 |    (will be garbage collected eventually)
             +------------+

             +------------+
fred/p ----> | TOM    999 |
             +------------+
```

Comment: That's a good old-school visual explanation.  Gotta love pluses, minuses and pipes in diagrams.  :)

Comment: +1. Quality answer that. Even helped me understand it clearer.

Comment: I like it so much Thank you.I knew about reference but you helped me a lot in clearance of what a pointer is doing.Approved

Comment: Once a reference is no longer used, it is immediately tagged for garbage collection. btw nice work. +1

Answer (score 4):

Because **just the reference** of the `Person p` is passed **not reference of the reference**.

You need to do this in order to pass the Person by reference.:

```
public static void SendAPersonByValue(ref Person p)
{
    p.age = 99;

    p = new Person("TOM", 999);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the person *reference* in the main to change to a *new reference* then one has to put the ref in the parameter list. Otherwise the stack has a reference to a location which main uses. It can change internal properties, but not the *reference* which main holds to the item it passed in.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have created a new reference. If you want the behavior that you expected you will have to change your SendAPersonByValue method to be `ref Person p`.

So, what is happening here is this:

```
SendAPersonByValue(fred);
//You are passing the value of fred's reference here
...
public static void SendAPersonByValue(Person p)
{
    p.age = 99;
    //The value of Fred's reference is used to populate his age

    p = new Person("TOM", 999);
    //p is now assigned to a totally new reference.
    //Because value's are immutable, fred remains
    //However, p is now pointing to a different reference value
}
```

What happens when you add ref to your method signature:

```
SendAPersonByValue(ref fred);
//A reference (pointer) to Fred's reference value is passed
...
public static void SendAPersonByValue(Person p)
{
    p.age = 99;
    //The pointer of the reference of Fred is used to populate his age
    //Ultimately, this is the same as above because the both end up at Fred

    p = new Person("TOM", 999);
    //The reference value of p (fred) is now the new reference 
    //since it was just a pointer to the reference value
}
```

[Here is a good article on the subject of values and references](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

When you assign the variable p in the method `SendAPersonByValue(Person p)` you only assign it locally. It does not change `fred` in your main method.

You can return the modified person and replace fred in the main method, or you can use the `ref` keyword.